# Touch ID/Face ID authentication inside app

Tags: ios, localauthentication

I need to authorize the user inside the app by using touch id or face id. I searched about this issue, but all solutions are for user login. In my case, I need to authorize the user again inside the one state of app. For instance, assume that the user logs in to my app. There is a buy button in my app and when the user clicks on it, I want to authenticate the user once more. Is there any solution for this issue? 
Thanks

Comment: You can use the local authentication framework to request a biometric verification.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic